# Algorithm for routing in a public transport network

Tags: c#, algorithm, path, routes, graph-algorithm

I'm projecting an algorithm to find a path in a public transport network, but I don't know how to make it simple, I'm thinking to this from yesterday. My objective is to find a path that minimize the bus changes, and other path that don't mind about bus changes, but they have to be short in time). This second algorithm is a k-shortest path algorithm (probably k = 3 or 4), for which I don't know any efficient implementation. I'd like to implement the two algorithms in C# and apply it to a real public transport network. 
Any hint?
Excuse me for my very bad English, but I'm from Italy :)

Answer (score 3):

A very common pathfinding algorithm is the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

A lot of implementations in c# can be found, for example here on [Codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/article.php/c12527/AStar-A-Implementation-in-C-Path-Finding-PathFinder.htm) or here on [msdn](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/pathfinding1).

You can find other ideas on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138642/simplest-c-sharp-implementation-of-a-algorithm).

Maybe you should use that and ponderate bus changes or something like that.

Comment: As upper, I already knew A* algorithm, but how can I modify it to give a weight to the bus changes?

Comment: It should be possible by defining the heuristic to be higher when changing bus, what do you think ?

Comment: @litiales Define each path with two segments: 1) path length (i.e. distance or time), and 2) a connector path that represents transitioning onto that path where no transfer would have a weight of 0, but a transfer would have some weight. So the total path weight would be the sum of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Dijkstra's-Algorithm. Try here as a start.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19919/Shortest-Path-Problem-Dijkstra-s-Algorithm

Comment: I already knew Dijkstra's algorithm but how can I modify that to reduce bus changes? It "easely" finds shortest path, without checking for bus changes.